# Compare geometries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry

Let us say, there are two tables, table1 and table2. Both have one column (geometry_1 and geometry_2 respectively) of text type.

```
    table1

    geometry_1
    text
1   LINESTRING(37.00 59.00, 37.05 59.32)
.... 


    table2

    geometry_2
    text
1   LINESTRING(37.89 59.55, 38.05 60.3)
....
```

Both tables have more rows, but for now I want to focus on the following question. Is there any way to evaluate if there are "similar" geometries between the tables. By "similar"? I mean that if the distance between the respective points of the lines is no higher than a certain value (eg. 100m), the two lines are considered identical.

I have tried this:

```
select geometry_1 from table1 t1
    where exists(
             select 1 from table2 t2  where 
             (select ST_Equals(ST_GeomFromText(t1.geometry_1),ST_GeomFromText(t2.geometry_2)) = true));
```

However the query takes too long. I m not sure if what I wrote is correct.

1. There are only linestrings with two or more vertices
2. Linestings with reversed directions are considered identical
3. If lines have more vertices and vertex B is in the middle of the line so that it does not bend the line,  A-B-C, A-C, A-B, B-A and C-B are identical
4. SRID=4326

Update1:

```
create index geom_1_idx ON table1 USING GIST (geometry_1);
select table1_id, table2_id  from table1 t1, table2 t2
              where (select st_DWithin(t1.geometry_2 , t2.geometry_2, units_of_srid) = true)
```

Consider it as initial approach to the problem regardless the above conditions

Comment: Probably there is a way but I believe that you must define your case more accurately. Do you have only linestrings with two vertices as in your example? Are linestings with reversed directions identical (A-B same as B-A)? If lines can have more vertices and vertex B is in the middle of the line so that it does not bend the line, would A-B-C and A-C be identical for you.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include the SQL you've developed to date, which should include an `a.id <> b.id` and a test involving `ST_Within` and `ST_Buffer`.  You should also specify the SRID in the question

Comment: ST_Equals does not accept any tolerance in coordinates. Line direction does not matter but it is still not your function. Perhaps if used together with ST_Snap but not alone.

Comment: There is no way to make this query operate in other than `O(N^^2)` time unless you load the geometries as `geometry` and create a spatial index, then do a self-join with a spatial constraint.

Comment: You can do this with ST_DWithin, although as Vince says, you will want spatial indexes for this to work efficiently.

Comment: Hi, check please the update. Is it correct? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the ideas from the comments into code, you get something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_geometrytype AS
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geometry_1) AS geom
FROM table1
;

CREATE INDEX ON table1_geometrytype USING gist(geom);

CREATE TABLE table2_geometrytype AS
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geometry_2) AS geom
FROM table2
;

CREATE INDEX ON table2_geometrytype USING gist(geom);

SELECT t1.geom
FROM
    table1_geometrytype AS t1
JOIN
    table2_geometrytype AS t2
ON
    ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100) -- assuming your SRID has meters as units
    AND
    ST_Equals(ST_Snap(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100), t2.geom) 
;
```